# Is it possible to implement a Service Server on Robot Web Tools?

Tags: robotwebtools, res-noetic

I am trying to implement a service server using roslibjs on a browser. Is it possible? There does not seem to have an `advertise` function available.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
This may help: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/838798d0c31866231b2c6fe95c5110fa2dc64f61/examples/simple.html#L110-L126